# How to sketch/graph the conic section $2x^2−4xy+5y^2=36$ in the (x, y)-plane by making use of the coordinate transformations $2(x−y)^2+3(y)^2 =36$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, rotations

How do I sketch/graph the conic section $$2x^2−4xy+5y^2=36$$ in the (x, y)-plane by making use of the coordinate transformations $$2(x−y)^2+3(y)^2 =36$$
With $x'=x-y$ and $y'=y$, so
$$2(x')^2+3(y')^2 =36$$

Comment: You can see that the conic will be an ellipse. Draw it in the $x',y'$-plane, then do the reverse transformation (find $x$ and $y$ in terms of $x'$ and $y'$). It might help to draw a box around the ellipse (i.e., $x' = \pm 3\sqrt2$ and $y' = \pm 2\sqrt3$) and see what happens to that box when you transform it back.

Comment: @Théophile Apologies, but I don't understand exactly how to do reverse transformation, could you explain or demonstrate it?

Comment: Sure: it's probably simpler than you think. We already have $y'=y$, so going the other way, $y=y'$. As for $x$, from $x'=x-y$, we have $x = x'+y = x'+y'$. In short: $(x,y) = (x'+y', y')$. From there, take any point $(x',y')$ on your ellipse, and you can transform it back to regular $(x,y)$ co-ordinates. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Théophile Yes but in that case I don't really see the logic of the whole use of the transformation, sort of what makes it different than it was before

Comment: The point is that it's easy to draw the new ellipse in $(x',y')$ because it aligns with the axes; you can look at the equation and immediately tell how wide and tall it is.

Comment: Yes I agree, but in my view it is not now the case that it is easier to sketch, because what you say you know the length and the width, but you do not yet know how they are rotated relative to the axes. I was hoping that the length and width would line up with the x axis and the y axis which made sketching even easier